# EF6 PK and FK constraint naming conventions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, naming-conventions, code-first

I primarily use Fluent NHibernate, where I can easily create a foreign key and/ or primary key constraint naming convention, but I'm having a deuce of a time figuring out how to do the same thing in EF6.

I want my PKs to look like `pkFoo` for table `dbo.Foo`, and my FKs to look like `fkBar.BarId_Foo.BarId` when linking tables `dbo.Foo` and `dbo.Bar` on the similar columns `BarId`, with the table that is alphanumerically first named first.

I took a look at inheriting from `PrimaryKeyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention`, but there does not seem to be a way to actually change the constraint name.

Is this not possible in EF?  Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out it does not appear like it is possible but is being tracked for future releases:

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/1226

Comment: It does indeed look that way.  Thanks!